# react js map function can not render the custom component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, custom-component, map-function

here i am getting the post data from firestore and showing it to my own custom component.

here is a code of map function:

```
{posts.map(({ id, data: { name, description, message, photoUrl } }) => {
            console.log("data: ", name);
            <Post
                key={id}
                name={name}
                description={description}
                message={message}
                photoUrl={photoUrl} />
        })}
```

Here is my custom component code:

```
function Post({ name, description, message, photoUrl }) {
console.log("Function Call");
return (
    <div className='post'>
        <div className="post__header">
            <Avatar />
            <div className="post__info">
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="post__body">
            <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="post__buttons">
            <InputOption Icon={ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon}
                title='Like' color="gray" />
            <InputOption Icon={ChatOutlinedIcon}
                title='Comment' color="gray" />
            <InputOption Icon={ShareOutlinedIcon}
                title='Share' color="gray" />
            <InputOption Icon={SendOutlinedIcon}
                title='Send' color="gray" />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Post

can any one help me??

Comment: the callback passed to map is not `return`ing anything

Answer (score 0):

**map** function requires an object should be returned from the callback function.

Your code should be like this.

```js
{
       posts.map(({ id, data: { name, description, message, photoUrl } }) => {
            console.log("data: ", name);
             return  (  <Post
                      key={id}
                      name={name}
                      description={description}
                      message={message}
                      photoUrl={photoUrl} /> )
        });
        
}
```